# Laravel debug bar not showing up after i canceled it in chrome but works on firefox

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website built using laravel and i have the debug bar active. The problem is that in chrome i canceled it by pressing the [x] at the far right of the bar and now i can't press on laravel icon to open it back up but it works perfectly in firefox(haven't pressed [x] yet in firefox).

I tried clearing route cache:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

But it is still not showing up in chrome(even tho i see the laravel icon (bottom left).

Any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have Javascript enabled in Chrome?

Comment: yes, the website works well(and it is using backbone.js) but the debug bur just won't show up :/

Comment: Try clearing the Chrome cookies, or access the site in private/guest mode

Comment: that was it! i had to clean the local storage!

Comment: I added an answer if you're willing to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with Laravel since it works in Firefox

Try clearing the Chrome cookies/local storage, or access the site in private/guest mode

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After recent changes in the Debugbar package you need to set

```
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=true
```

inside your `.env` file